# an alternative to webdriver's ContextClick(webelement)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've tried to use webdriver's ContextClick function to open the right-click menu of a webapp, however the  ContextClick  forces the browser's context menu, and not the menu that would appear if we would actually use the mouse right-click (the right click will open a webapp specific context menu)

is there a selenese alternative to ContextClick ?

Comment: i hope locator/webelement where contextClick performing is correct? same element as you are doing manual..correct?

Comment: good have that line of code

Comment: it turns out the issue was my mistake - i thought i was focused on the correct element when I was not. this is why the incorrect context menu appeared. After I fixed the locator the right context menu appeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"`contextClick()` or `contextClick(WebElement element)`" methods of Actions class can be used to perform right click.

Below is the sample code:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver).contextClick(element);
action.build().perform();
```

`contextClick()`
Performs a context-click at the current mouse location.

`contextClick(WebElement onElement)`
Performs a context-click at middle of the given element.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Use Actions class to simulate context click of html element.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver).contextClick(element);
action.build().perform();
```

In Selenium IDE:

> Use 'contextMenu' / 'contextMenuAt' to do a right-click. You cannot record this event in Selenium IDE.